# Persistent volume resizing on GCP - GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

As explained in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#expanding-persistent-volumes-claims
in order to resize Persistent Volume Claims online, some things has to be activated at cluster level:

- ExpandPersistentVolumes feature gate
- PersistentVolumeClaimResize admission plugin

Are this features enabled at GKE?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that on GKE, unfortunately. `ExpandPersistentVolumes` and `PersistentVolumeClaimResize` are api-server components, and on GKE you don't have access to the master node.

Note that you can't delete and create the PVC, as the pod won't get the new size. It will keep showing the previous size if doing `df -h`. for example. You will need to delete the pod, and re-create it.

Comment: What does it mean the they are API-server components? any referneces for that, and why GKE doesn't have access? Thank you

Comment: These features are manage by the kube-api server which is located on a master node. Since GKE is a hosted cloud service the the master node is hidden from the end-users and under the administrative control of the Google Cloud infrastructure team.